# PostgreSQL join across 2 databases

Tags: postgresql, select, join, subquery

I am new to PostgreSQL. I have 2 databases in PostgreSQL 9.0, db1 and db2, and with db2 I have read only access. I want to create a stored function that would be otherwise easily accomplished with a JOIN or a nested query, something PostgreSQL can't do across databases.

In db1, I have table1 where I can query for a set of foreign keys keys that I can use to search for records in a table2 in db2, something like:

```
SELECT * from db2.table2 WHERE db2.table2.primary_key IN (
    SELECT db1.table1.foreign_key FROM db1.table1 WHERE
        db1.table1.primary_key="whatever");
```

What is the best practice for doing this in Postgres? I can't use a temporary tables in db2, and passing in the foreign keys as a parameter in a stored function running in db2 doesn't seem like a good solution.

Note: the keys are all VARCHAR(11)

Comment: One option you may want to investigate is the use of Schemas: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/ddl-schemas.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to look into the [db_link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) contrib.

As an aside if you're familiar with C, there also is a cute functionality called [foreign data wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html). It allows to manipulate pretty much any source using plain SQL. [Example with Twitter](https://github.com/umitanuki/twitter_fdw):

```
SELECT from_user, created_at, text FROM twitter WHERE q = '#postgresql';
```

Comment: This seemed to work ok after installing dblink:

`SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table2
WHERE table2.primary_key IN(
    SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=db1 user=readonly',
      'SELECT foreign_key FROM table1 WHERE foreign_key=?')
    AS temp1(foreign_key varchar(11))
);`