# Application-level JOIN with WHERE and ORDER BY on N postgresql shards

Tags: postgresql, cluster-computing, sharding

I have a postgresql cluster with different tables residing within different shards (different physical postgresql servers). EG:

shard A
+ user_group (user_group_id, user_group_name)

shard B
+ user (user_id, user_group_id (NULL), user_name)

shard C
+ comment (comment_id, user_id, comment_content)

I need to run queries that if all 3 tables where on the same shard, it would look something like:

SELECT comment_id, comment_content FROM comment INNER JOIN user ON comment.user_id = user.user_id LEFT JOIN user_group ON user.user_group_id = user_group.user_group_id WHERE user_group_id > 10 AND user_name LIKE 'foo%' ORDER BY user_group_name ASC, user_name ASC, comment_id ASC

How would such a query be implemented if the 3 tables are residing within 3 different physical postgresql shards?

I've read about references that one would have to 'do the join in the application layer' but I am not sure how to go about this. Some of the complexities include:
1. The cardinality of the different tables is unknown (or can change over time), so from the application layer (EG: php, python, etc...), we would not know if we should first go query user_group, get all the user groups, then query user, get all the users, etc..., or first query comment, get all the comments, then filter the retrieved comments by users, then filter by user groups, etc...

I am looking for a generic way to translate sql into application-level joins, and the above schema is only a hypothetical example.

Answer (score 2):

Usually data divides at shards in a way which allow to avoid cross-server JOINS at all. Because this operation is difficult and expensive. If your example is hypothetical I would recommend divide all data by user_id field or user_group_id.

For example shard A will contain all tables with information from users which user_id % 3 = 0, shard B - which user_id % 3 = 1, shard C - which user_id % 3 = 2. So most of needed JOINS will be inside one shard. For some complex cross-server queries you may have common NO-SQL storage like memcached or Redis which will have copies of needed data from all shards (of course it's not full copy of all tables). Such storages can be easily replicated on as much servers as you need. This is how highload projects works.

Comment: Yes I understand that it is sub-optimal to have joins between shards. Unfortunately I am stuck with the scenarios for various reasons and I do not have the option to change the sharding schema. The original question is more about asking how to do 'application-level sharding' that is referenced in many NOSQL articles but none of those articles ever seems to provide an actual pseudo-code example in say php on how to do it.

Comment: Are you aware of links, tutorials, resources or videos showing how to implement such architectures? Thank you! How to scale this so that you can add an arbitrary number of servers into the mix? Redistribution of data, data denormalisation, hot key problem, etc... What are the best ways to handle these tasks? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the [db_link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) contrib.

Comment: I read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink.html but it seems that db_link only enables the querying of another pg instance from a SQL query, but does not support joins? Can you provide a example query that uses dblink() which achieves the same effect as the join query in the question (SELECT comment_id...)?

Comment: @archmeta: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295837/postgresql-join-across-2-databases (MuffinMan's comment on my answer has an example.)

Comment: Thanks it seems that db_link can be used to support joins. That being said, is there a way to do the application-level joining using 100% php (or any other language), without using something like dblink?

Comment: Without dblink, won't you end up needing to pull the applicable result set from both servers and joining them in PHP? It seems somewhat inefficient... Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the question...

Comment: Yes dblink definitely sounds like the more efficient option when the external data source is another pgsql server. The original question was intended to get a better understanding of an application-level algorithm that can be used to query for data in various data stores of different types and then doing the join within the application. EG: According to this article (http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/news_ebay_massive_oracle.htm), "all sorting and SQL joins are handled within the application layer". I am trying to get a better understanding as to how one may actually do that.

Comment: Well, it's the three join types (nest loop, hash and merge) implemented in the app's language. I'd assume you'd fetch the sets, collect some stats, join and ***cache***. also note that ebay's issues are very different from yours or mine.

Comment: The point about 'you'd fetch the sets' is where I am having the most trouble with. In order to execute the join logic with the ORDER BY in the original question, unless I knew the cardinality of every column (thereby essentially writing a query planner in the app layer, which I want to avoid), I would have to retrieve all the rows for all the joined tables, in order to do the order by in the app layer. Is there a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: "Is there a more efficient algorithm?" - Not that I'm aware of. If anything, the lack of any is the whole point of doing the join from within the (same) database...