# implement activity stream in django (message broke maybe?)

Tags: django

I am building like a social network website using django, and I need to implement a news feed.I think this is the hardest part in the social website.

I've been reading, and I've seen things like using a message broker (rabbitmq for example) to implement the activity stream or just using simpler things in Django.

I honestly don't know where to start, and also have no idea how an activity stream should work, from the architecture point of view. is using a message broker the correct way? I'd like to implement one, since I've never did, but don't know if it will be too much work for such a simple thing. Could anybody give me some light on what direction should I take for this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of scaling, you can do it with just Django models and the database but as the number of users increases the number of interactions multiplies. Probably you can go a long way with just basic Django, but big social websites don't do it this way.

Part of the problem is: how do you know which of Jane's friends should be able to see the message that Jane just posted? This is not hard, but you'll end up joining several tables in the SQL query. At 'web scale' this is problem because joins can be slow, also you have so many users your db is sharded across multiple servers (probably can't join across the shards! https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717063/202168).

This is why sites like Twitter or Facebook will be using some kind of 'NoSQL' datastore. These kind of dbs are designed to scale easily and stay fast at scale, but at the expense of features like foreign keys, joins etc. What do you do if you can't join? You end up 'denormalizing' the data... basically copying the values from related tables into the places they are needed. This means the 'reads' of the data are fast, but you have to do more work when you save a new status... probably you have to insert a copy of the new message into a table for each recipient or something like that.

Now you find you want to de-couple the act of a user posting a status update (saving a single record in the db) from the act of broadcasting that message to the feeds of relevant user connections... because this latter action requires too many db updates and takes too long, making things feel slow.

This is where the message broker comes in... instead of doing all the work at the point where the user clicks 'send', you just do the minimum: save the post to the db and forward a 'new status posted' task to the message broker... the rest happens later 'asynchronously'.

A useful property of the broker is the idea of a 'queue' of messages. In other words you can push messages onto the queue faster than they are being popped off (eg during a spike in activity) and the queue will just grow, rather than getting an error back from an overloaded db. Later when the spike has passed your workers will still be popping messages off the queue... hopefully fast enough to empty it before the next spike!

Another benefit is the broker, workers, db nodes, web servers can all be scaled independently as needed.

Generally for a message broker/task queue system in Python you'll want to use Celery:
http://www.celeryproject.org

On a practical level you can use the signals from @vadimchin's answer to add your task to the Celery queue.

Comment: excellent answer! you have clarified a lot of concepts, I will definitely research about Celery and try to use with signals

Comment: I would add: right now your app has zero users, maybe it's a niche network of some kind and will never have so many users that you need to scale beyond a well-configured PostgreSQL db... I'd suggest maybe you're best to forget about the complication of Celery etc initially and just build a basic Django version first.

Comment: On the other hand, if you realistically anticipate having all the scaling issues then Django isn't the best choice. For example the ORM only works with SQL databases (needs hacks and helpers to use NoSQL backends eg http://django-nonrel.org/). Also the more software and machines you have to install and configure just to get your site up and running the more headaches you have, it's a lot for one person to deal with.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will analyse the pros and cons of each approach and take a decision.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way: create signal, and model something like

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_type = .... # 1 - new photo, 2 - news, 3 - new video etc.
    title =
    content = 


def create_event_record(sender, user, source,event_type, title, content, **kwargs):
   ...
```

call the signal from views

on client side - get pack of events, for example 100. Put it in client cache (using jscript), and rotate. When all events rotated, get new part of data from server.

Comment: nice! I've never heard about signals, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile you can use [django-activity-stream](https://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this. It is actively maintained and follows the principle to break down activities in the following way:

```
Actor: Users or bots
Verb: Pushed or starred
Action Object: Commits, pull requests, or nothing
Target: Repository or organization
```

You will also find a useful extension in the web, in form of an article here

- [django-activity-stream-with-django-rest-framework](https://andrew.hawker.io/writings/2020/11/16/django-activity-stream-with-django-rest-framework/)